# Is there a faster/better way to do this simple iteration in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
for node in nodes{
    names.append(node.name)
}
```

I just wrote this code and it *felt* like I was doing it the slow/noob way, thinking about my experiences with Python and Swift so far, and just thought I should ask.

Comment: Does `names` contain data prior to this that you want to preserve or is `names` empty when you start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't show the declaration of `names`. I'll assume your code looks like this:

```
var names: [String] = []
for node in nodes {
    names.append(node.name)
}
```

If so, you could write it like this:

```
let names = nodes.map { $0.name }
```

or like this:

```
let names = nodes.map(\.name)
```

On the other hand, if `names` might already contain some values you want to preserve, you could do this:

```
names.append(contentsOf: nodes.lazy.map(\.name)
```

The use of `.lazy` here prevents Swift from creating a temporary array just to hold the new names.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know if this is faster in execution than what I did originally, or if it runs the same and just looks better?

Comment: I'd guess it runs at very close to the same speed, but you would have to profile it to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `map`. Assuming that `names` doesn't exist when we start, you could just say

```
let names = nodes.map {$0.name}
```

Comment: How would you read that line out in english? Kinda like if I had “int[] nums;” I would say nums is an array of integers. I feel like that would help me understand what map is doing better

Comment: Basically you are asking me to teach you most of Swift in a comment. That's not viable.

Comment: No I am not. I just showed you an example of what I wanted.  Thanks anyways

Comment: I took a stab at trying to figure it out myself and I came up with 
 this: "let names be an array equal to the following: the existing nodes array, where each element of nodes, referred to temporarily as $0 has its respective names property selected and set as the respective element in names array"